# Connection issue R elastic package for Elastic search - one way entry

Tags: r, elasticsearch, connection, httr

I have acces to an oneway export function to a public company database through Elastic Search. I have problems connection to it from R and the elastic package.

I have server name(URL), username and password, but I don't have any port number.  They describe it as a rest API. Do I have to use the elastic package or is there an easier way around it. The only information I have to the database is: http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/virksomhed/_search?.
 `Host="Distribution.virk.dk"
index="cvr-permanent"
type="virksomhed"`

The above link works with HTTR, but I wish to use elastic for automation purposes, when making a large request of data.

so my connect looks like

```
host = "distribution.virk.dk"  
port = ''  
path = ''  
schema = "http"  
user = "user_name"  
pass = "secret"  

connect(es_host = host,es_user=user, transport=schema, port=port, es_pwd = pass)
```

Even though I set port to blank it returns 9200.

If I try to use Search

```
>Search(index="cvr-permanent", type="virksomhed", q='"cvrNummer":"33647093"', size=10)  
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
    Failed to connect to distribution.virk.dk port 9200: Timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

(`elastic` maintainer here)

You should be able to pass in `httr::authenticate()` to `elastic::Search` and other functions from the pkg, e.g,.

```
x <- Search(config = c(httr::verbose(), authenticate("foo", "bar")))
```

You should see the `Authorization: Basic XXXXXX` header in the request headers

does that work?

Comment: I keep getting the following error no matter how I change the code. 


`Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL`

Comment: Can you reinstall `devtools::install_github("ropensci/elastic")` and try again

Comment: Just tried it, but same result unfortunately. Am I missing a term in the code? I am not that familiar with the verbose()function.

Comment: updated example above, it's `httr::verbose()`, prints verbose curl output, headers and such

Comment: Gives the same error, but I have tried it with httr::GET, which works. But still have issues formatting the data.  `> GET /cvr-permanent/_search HTTP/1.1  
-> Host: distribution.virk.dk
-> Authorization: Basic Q0xFQU5fQ1ZSX0lfU0tZRU46OWJjMWMxMDYtYjg5Yi00YmJkLThmODEtNjU4Yjc1NTJhZTY4
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.53.1 r-curl/2.6 httr/1.2.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
<- Date: Fri, 23 Jun 2017 07:09:18 GMT
<- Server: nginx/1.10.2
<- Content-Length: 83894`

Comment: I have tried all the things you have suggested, with no luck unfortunately. I have managed to connect to the server using connect(). But when I use Search() I get the following error?   `Error in if (gsub("\\.", "", ping()$version) >= 500) args$lenient <- NULL : 
  argument is of length zero`  I am guessing it's because they use an older version of elasticsearch, but how can I come around it?

Comment: sorry about the trouble - what does `ping()$version` give you?

Comment: It gives >error: 400 - ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No feature for name [API]]. Not sure What this mean?

Comment: Looks like the connection not being set up correctly - are you sure you can connect to it at all? does it work just with curl on the command line?  if you want, you can email me your username/pwd so i can try

Comment: Yes I have succeeded using HTTR at least. So I know I have access.

Comment: Dear Sckott, 

The danish Business agency have now updated their elasticsearch api to the most recent version. I have been able to do the call so far through the HTTR. They used v1.74 before. So it is possible for me to connect to the site, but I'd rather use the elastic package if possible.

Comment: Dear @sckott 

The danish Business agency has updated their api to the most recent version. I have been able to do the call so far through the HTTR. They used v1.74 before. So it is possible for me to connect to the site, but I'd rather use the elastic package if possible. 

It is a oneway API, meaning I can only get data out, but not update data. I have so far used the following URL to make my calls with HTTR _"http://distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/_search?"_. 

My question is - If I am to use the elastic package do I have to set up connect or can I just use Search someway?

Comment: You should still be able to use `elastic` pkg. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: I have tried, but as the last time I think I am failing doing, what I believe should be the most simple part. connecting to the api with Elastic.  I am trying to put the url as discribed above into the connection without the _search? bit.  So connect looks like: < `connect(es_host='distribution.virk.dk/cvr-permanent/', es_user=username, port='', es_pwd=pass`.   with inf<-ping()$version returns null.  I have tried doing a Search, but gives errors such as:    _Error: 405 - Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/cvr-permanent/:9200] and method [GET], allowed: [POST]_

Comment: Dear Scott I have updated my original post and I have one question. You mentioned it is possible to pass in HTTR arguments in the SEARCH function. >> When using the connect function I am trying to set port to blank, because I only want to use the URL really. 


Is it possible to insert URL directly into Search with the config function?

Comment: at this point we should probably take discussion off here, open an issue here https://github.com/ropensci/elastic/issues/

Comment: fair enough, I will